# Как расставить шейдером вектор точек/частиц

Tags: c++, opengl, шейдеры, glsl

Я пишу на C++ в связке с OpenGL (glsl).
Задача такая: у меня есть набор точек и либо эти точки вычисляют фрагменты шейдера, либо я их имею на части кода CPU и передаю в шейдер. Меня интересует, есть ли способ отобразить эти точки кроме способа, где каждый фрагмент проверяет свою причастность для каждой из точки/частицы, и в случае успеха закрашивает. Так я не получу никакого прироста производительности, да и придётся выгружать данные с видеопамяти в память процессора.
Т.е. хочется иметь возможность в фрагменте менять соседние данные текстур, а не только out type FragColor. Я понимаю, что проблема в конвейере и параллельности вычисления кода у видеокарт, но неужели нельзя просто решать конфликты между перезаписью какого-то числа с помощью битовых масок, или суммирования вместо перезаписи? (может как-то через layout и дополнительные текстуры)
Подобного рода не графические вычисления можно делать на CUDA и т.п., но мне хочется сохранить простоту проекта с вычислением клеточных автоматов на glsl файлах с открытым кодом.

Comment: Точки следует обрабатывать в вершинном шейдере. А пиксельный должен работать с уже готовыми данными. В пиксельном шейдере можно без проблем менять содержимое текстур, достаточно назначить текстуру в качестве цели рендера.

Comment: @user7860670, вот пример задачи. У нас спирограф, который от аргумента t выдаёт x и y где нужно поставить точку. GPU считает эти точки в 100 раз быстрее CPU, но не мне не известно, как записать результат, т.е. прибавить текстуре по координатам x y единицу.

Comment: В таком случае сначала следует сделать геометрический шейдер, который для заданной точки рассчитывал бы геометрию. Возможно даже двухпроходный и/или вычислительный, если нужно получить качественную растеризацию, как у векторного рисунка. Т.е. последовательность будет примерно такая: параметры спирали -> набор вершин геометрии  спирали -> набор вершин геометрии линий (с учетом нужной толщины линии и антиалиасинга) -> рендер растровой картинки в текстуру